# "quantifying" business problems the right word?

Tags: vocabulary

I am searching for the correct word which describes the process of measuring a problem and trying to express it with numbers. So from text to numbers. I thought "quantifying" should be the right word, but I am not sure if it is correct in this context. I want to use it in my cover letter for job application. Something like this maybe:

> Quantifying and solving business problems is my passion and I am
>   always eager to accept new challenges.

Is this correct, does it translate?

Comment: If you could explain a little more what you mean by quantifying, there's a better chance the suggestions will fit your need. An effort to be concise has to start out with an understanding of the full meaning or intent.

Comment: Well I just want to use this as a sentence in my cover letter for a job application. I studied business administration and statistics, so I wanted to emphasize that I am able to "quantify" business problems. So to somehow use a statistical methodology to solve e.g. a case study, a business problem. That's what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Here's what I would suggest, to capture your intent:

> Quantitative analysis of business problems is my passion and I am always eager to accept new challenges.

or

> Quantitative analysis (of business problems) using statistical methodology is my passion and I am always eager to accept new challenges.

You may choose to leave the parenthetical part out.

Since there are other aspects to business problems than just the quantitative aspect, I would leave *quantitative* in the statement.

I'm not sure how important it is to you that the word *solving* be a part of the statement, but it could be inferred from the whole statement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most normal word to use in this context is *framing* for which google gives the following definitions that are meaningful:

> create or formulate (a concept, plan, or system).
>
> form or articulate (words).

The ambiguity about quantifying is that it can describe both turning the problem into a numerically solvable system and measuring the values for the numerically solvable system that exists. The former is figuring out that you should count your chickens and the volume of their excrement. The latter is measuring the weight of their excrement.

Comment: Thanks for your post! My question is: Can I use the word quantifying in this context? But I am not THAT precise as you are. So I see your point, but this wouldn't bother? I think the sentence would still work? So if this is the only problem it wouldn't be a problem. But I was not sure if I can use "Quantifying" at all in this context, but it seems to me, as your post shows?!

Answer (score 0):

I think the single word would be (statistical) **analysis/analyze**.  You might also want to think about working ROI into your language if that fits you.